# Prove $\mathrm{Hom}_{R}(M_{1}, M_{2})=K$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_{R}(M_{2},M_{1})= 0$ for $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ modules over a matrix ring and $K$ a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Filling a gap of an example I got the following problem:

> Let $K$ be a field. If we consider the ring $$R=\begin{pmatrix} K & 0\\ K^{(\mathbb{N})} & K \end{pmatrix}$$ and the idempotents $\epsilon_{a}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\epsilon_{b}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and let $\epsilon_{1}$ the first entry at the canonical basis of $K^{(\mathbb{N})}$, then put $S=R\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ \epsilon_{1} & 0 \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ K \epsilon_{1} & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Set $M_{1}= R \epsilon_{a}$ and $M_{2}= \frac{R \epsilon_{a}}{S}$. What I want to prove is that $\mathrm{Hom}_{R}(M_{1}, M_{2})=K$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_{R}(M_{2},M_{1})= 0$.

For me this has maybe something related to $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ are simple. So far I have noted that $R \cong \epsilon_{b}$ and

$$R= \epsilon_{a} \oplus \epsilon_{b}= \begin{pmatrix} K & 0\\ K^{\mathbb{N}} & 0 \end{pmatrix} \oplus \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & K \end{pmatrix}.$$

For proving, $Hom_{R}(M_{1}, M_{2}) \cong K$ lets take $g \in  Hom_{R}(M_{1},M_{2})$ and also consider the projection $\pi:M_{1} \to M_{2}=\frac{M_{1}}{S}$ so as we can factor this morphism $h$ into applying a morphism $f: M_{1} \to M_{1}$ and then $\pi$ but $f$ consist only in multiplying  any $\begin{pmatrix} x & 0\\ \bar{v} & 0 \end{pmatrix} \in M_{1}$ with $\begin{pmatrix} a & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ where $a \in K$. What I need to prove to show that $Hom_{R}(M_{1}, M_{2}) \cong K$ is that $a \in K$ in $f$ is unique for the factorization $h=\pi f$. [image]

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something, but doesn't left-multiplication by the idempotent $\epsilon_a$ give you a map $M_1 \rightarrow M_1$ which is $0$ on $S$ (and thus a nonzero map $M_2 \rightarrow M_1$)?

Comment: Multiplying $\epsilon_{a}$ at the left of $M_{1}$? @BadamBaplan

Comment: yes that is what I mean

Comment: Sorry, still thinking about how you get that not zero morphims @BadamBaplan

Comment: The map sends an element $A \in M_1$ to the element $\epsilon_a A \in M_1$.  This has the effect of sending $RS \subseteq M_1$ to $0$.  Right?

Comment: Sorry for the last response, I got saturated by the end of semester. You are right! Was thinking about your idea. Now Im trying  to prove $Hom(M_{1},M_{2}) \cong K$, Im already editing original question with my idea to prove this. Tell me what u think about it, please @BadamBaplan

Answer (score 1):

We showed in the comments that $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M_2, M_1) \not= 0$.  Namely the map $M_1 \rightarrow M_1$ defined by sending $A \in M_1$ to $\epsilon_aA \in M_1$ restricts to $0$ on $S \subseteq M_1$, so that map factors through $M_2 = M_1/S$ and is not zero on $M_2$ because it fixes $\epsilon_a \in M_1 \setminus S$.

For the second part of your question, you wondered if $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M_1, M_2) \cong K$.

This is also false.  For example, an easy consideration comes from cardinality.  For any $a \in K, b \in K^{(\mathbb{N})}$, we get a map sending an element $A \in M_1$ to the coset $\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ b & 0\end{bmatrix}\cdot A + S \in M_2$.  If $b, b'$ are elements that differ away from the first coordinate of $K^{(\mathbb{N})}$, then the corresponding maps are distinct, by definition of $S$.  There are way to many of these homomorphisms to be in correspondence with elements of $K$.  If $K$ is finite, there are already uncountably many of these homomorphisms.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meaned that $Hom_{R}(M_{2},M_{1})=0$ I already proved In fact this is true, also $Hom_{R}(M_{1},M_{2}) \cong K$ as this part of some article. I think the way you define a morphism from $M_{1} \to M_{1}$ is not well defined as its supposed to  only take a matrix in $M_{1}$ and multiply like the matrix you defined but $b \in K^{\mathbb{N}}$ is always zero. @BadamBaplan

Comment: @Cos Why don't you link to the article? That certainly would help to clear things up.

Comment: @BadamBaplam This is Remark 2.16 (c) does not imply (a) for Tilting Modules and Tilting torsion theories by Colpi and Trlifaj. I wanted to send u a picture how I proved this assuming of course this question about some Hom set equal to zero and the othe Hom set isomorphic to $K$ but Math stack dont let me upload this as it weights a lot.

Comment: @BadamBaplam Also wondering if you have and idea for this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3717230/for-bigoplus-n-leq-0-mathbbz-pn-the-classes-operatornamegen-big?noredirect=1#comment7642616_3717230

Comment: @Cos All I see at Remark 2.16 is a reference to another paper.

Comment: Yes, that's why I want to upload a photo. Let me try it again

Comment: Already uploaded the counterexample in the refered paper @BadamBaplan

Comment: @Cos I'm confused.  I don't see how the homomorphisms I defined, which are just left-multiplication by elements of $R$, could be ill-defined.  But sometimes I can be astonishingly dense, it's all too possible.  Anyways, I answered the question you linked to.  Best of luck with your studies.

Comment: Thanks a lot helping me into this fascinating but also hard  world of module theory @BadanBaplan