# For $\bigoplus_{n \leq 0}\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$, the classes $\operatorname{Gen}(\bigoplus_{n \leq 0}\mathbb{Z}_{p^n})$ and $p$ torsion groups are equal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let's consider a prime number $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ and the group $M=  \bigoplus_{n \leq 0}\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ (this means $M=\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p^3} \oplus\cdots$) which is a module over $\mathbb{Z}$. I want to prove that $\operatorname{Gen}(M)=T_p$ where
$$T_p:= \lbrace G \mid G \text{ is a $p$-torsion group}\rbrace,$$
where a group $G$ is $p$-torsion means that for every $g \in G$ we have that $p^k g= e$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Also,

$$\operatorname{Gen}(M):= \lbrace N \in \operatorname{Mod}(\mathbb{Z}) \mid M^{(X)} \twoheadrightarrow N \rbrace$$

where $\operatorname{Mod}(\mathbb{Z})$ is the category of modules over $\mathbb{Z}$ and $M^{(X)} \twoheadrightarrow N$ is a surjective map from arbitrary number of direct copies of $M$ into $N$. I need help proving both contentions, so far I have noticed that $M \in \operatorname{Gen}(M)$ since we have $1_{M}:M  \twoheadrightarrow M$ and that $M=  \bigoplus_{n \leq 0}\mathbb{Z}_{p^{n}} \in T_{p}$ my intuition says that $\operatorname{Gen}(M) \subseteq T_{p}$ is the easy contention.  For the $T_p \subseteq \operatorname{Gen}(M)$ contention my idea is to use that if $G \in T_p$ then we can think $G=\sum_{g \in G} \mathbb{Z}_{g}$ where  $\mathbb{Z}_g \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^m}$ for some $0<m \in \mathbb{Z}$ so we have a surjection

$$ \bigoplus_{g \in G} \mathbb{Z}_{g} \twoheadrightarrow \sum_{g \in G} \mathbb{Z}_{g}=G$$

and each $\bigoplus_{g \in G} \mathbb{Z}_{g}$ is a direct summand of $M^{(G)}$. Thanks!

Comment: If you're writing about this sort of math, there are things you ought to know about standard LaTeX usage. See my edits to this question.

Comment: *NB:* `${\rm text}$` works just as well as `$\operatorname{text}$`. Look: ${\rm text}$ vs. $\operatorname{text}$, @MichaelHardy.

Comment: @Shaun : You're very much mistaken. Look: $3{\rm kos} x$ versus $3\operatorname{kos}x$ versus $3\operatorname{kos}(x).$ Notice the spacing to the left and right of "kos" in the second example, which uses \operatorname{kos}, and the lack of space in the first, which uses {\rm }, and the difference between the second and third examples in the amount of space to the right of "kos", where no manually added spacing is present. The second and third both use \operatorname{}. Furthermore, using \operatorname{} sometimes affects the formatting of subscripts and superscripts. $\qquad$

Comment: I stand corrected, @MichaelHardy; thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is right on track, I think, although I am confused by your approach to writing $G$ as a sum in the end of the proof, so my answer might be approaching that differently than you had intended.

$\operatorname{Gen}(M) \subseteq T_p$

Suppose that $N$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module such that there is an index set $X$ and a surjection $f: M^{(X)} \twoheadrightarrow N$.  Note that $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ is $p$-torsion, and that a direct sum of modules is $p$-torsion if (and only if) its summands are $p$-torsion, and thus conclude that $M$ is $p$-torsion and furthermore $M^{(X)}$ is $p$-torsion.  Next, note that homomorphic images of $p$-torsion modules are $p$-torsion, and thus conclude that $N$ is $p$-torsion.

$T_p \subseteq \operatorname{Gen}(M)$

Suppose that $G$ is a $p$-torsion group. Thinking of $G$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, this just means that for all $g \in G$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p^n g = 0$.  We can view $G$ as a colimit of its finitely generated submodules.  Each of these f.g. submodules decomposes as $\bigoplus_{i=1}^k \mathbb{Z}/d_i\mathbb{Z}$ where $d_i \mid d_{i+1}$ (here we are appealing to, say, the structure theorem for f.g. modules over PIDs).  The fact that each element of this f.g. submodule is annihilated by $p^n$ for some $n$ implies that each $d_i$ is a power of $p$.  Thus $G$ is a colimit of finite direct sums of the form $\bigoplus_{i=1}^{k} \mathbb{Z}/p^{n_i}\mathbb{Z}$.  A colimit of modules is by definition a special quotient of their direct sum, so this gives us a representation of $G$ as the quotient of a module of the form $H = \bigoplus_{\alpha \in I} \mathbb{Z}/p^{n_\alpha}\mathbb{Z}$ where $I$ is some index set.  It is now straightforward to find an index set $X$ such that $M$ surjects onto $H$, and hence onto $G$ (because $G$ is a quotient of $H$).  For example, you could take $X = I$ and the map $f: M^{(I)} \twoheadrightarrow H$ defined componentwise as follows: the $f_\alpha$ component of $f$ maps the $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n_\alpha}\mathbb{Z}$ component of $M$ identically to the $\alpha$ component of $H$ (which is also $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n_\alpha}\mathbb{Z}$) and vanishes on the other components of $M$.